# what kind of cable do I use for this port

Tags: windows-xp, cable

Can you tell me what kind of port the larger circular port is as seen on this picture?

[image]

Comment: Are we really at the point that if it doesn't look like a USB charging port then it's unrecognizable? I feel old...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - it's not so much it's unrecognisable, but that it totally fails to include the necessary standard symbols to be able to find a replacement using the info on the port alone. The OP is going to need the manual.

Comment: @Tetsujin Has the symbol for DC power changed recently?

Comment: No, but it's short of important info. Voltage, amperage & polarity. All 3 symbols should be there. At least, unlike those stupid USB 2 ports, you don't have to try it three ways round before it fits :P

Comment: Look on the bottom of the device (docking station?) and see if there's a diagram with `+` and `-` symbols and the expression "Vdc".

Comment: @Tetsujin to my knowledge, the voltage and amperage are almost never near the port, but always on the sticker near the serial number, unless the port is so standard that there is an exception for that kind of port, such as usb.

Comment: Make and model number of the device would help.

Answer (score 8):

This port is for DC power, thus an AC/DC powerconverter. You need an adapter or powerbrick suited for this pc. Do note, not every adapter that has the same port will work. The voltage and amperage must also match the computer.

Comment: Although not specified by symbol, [polarity](https://www.accesscomms.com.au/power-supply-symbols/) also matters for this DC jack.

Comment: You can search for "Universal Laptop Charger" on your favorite e-commerce site for a replacement.

Comment: @LawrenceC - it might be 'universal' but unless the manual tells what voltage, amperage & polarity, you won't get too many free guesses before something goes bang.

Comment: LPChip - strictly speaking the port is for DC power. I know what you mean by AC/DC, that it it needs a transformer from one to the other… but it's not crystal clear if you don't understand the symbol implicitly.

Comment: Making this too complicated.  It really looks like one of the barrel-style Dell or HP connectors, not anything really freaky.  As long as you follow included directions on any universal adapter (make sure it is for a *laptop* and nothing else), you should be OK.  It is definitely better to try to get a replacement AC adapter for at least the same make of laptop, if not the same make/model.

Comment: @LawrenceC - that really is potentially dangerous advice. That socket type could be for literally anything from 1.5 to 25v [though it's likely to be for 12-24 on a laptop]. Get it wrong & you risk blowing the circuit.

Comment: @Tetsujin Edited the post even though my initial thought was, that it was clear enough.

Comment: @LPChip - Thanks. I know it is ‘obvious’ but just in case;)